# how to put a UICollectionView inside UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to make a `UIActionSheet` and style it same as the picture, but there are two things I don't know how to proceed:
1) How to put a `UICollectionView` in a `UIActionSheet`.
2) I want to make a paging style for my `UICollectionView` items.

[the example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZNCa.jpg)

Comment: u cant. you need to make it custom

Comment: Visit the link https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=Action+sheet

Comment: You can't really do that with the default `UIActionSheet`s, but even if you could, you should actually be using a `UIAlertController` as the former is deprecated